# What is a "no-shield look"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please, help me figure out how "no-shield look" can be interpreted.

> He (Keith Yandle) did so with his regular exuberance and kid-like energy, a "love for the game" that built an unprecedented run.
> Old-school, no-shield look for Keith Yandle today. Still got after it like he always does. pic.twitter.com/oBRpWvCzSs
> — Jordan Hall (@JHallNBCS) April 2, 2022

Answer (score 1):

This is about professional ice hockey. tl;dr: wearing a helmet without the face shield.

Shield is the face shield- a clear protection over the top half of the face. A “no-shield look” means wearing the helmet without the shield. “Look” in this case means the person’s appearance.

Based on an internet search, I learned that the shield became mandatory in 2013 in the NHL, but that players already in the league (with 25 games experience but whatever) were exempt from that rule. So jump ahead several years and few players remain who are allowed to go no-shield. So it is considered “old-school”.

This is similar to when they required helmets but allowed players already in the league to forgo the helmet. I make no claim on if being “old-school” by forgoing safety equipment is wise.